# Uploading large files to Google Storage GCE from a Kubernetes pod

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

We get this error when uploading a large file (more than 10Mb but less than 100Mb):

```
403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/dm-scrapes/o?uploadType=resumable: ('Response headers must contain header', 'location')
```

Or this error when the file is more than 5Mb

```
403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/dm-scrapes/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

It seems that this API is looking at the file size and trying to upload it via multi part or resumable method. I can't imagine that is something that as a caller of this API I should be concerned with. Is the problem somehow related to permissions? Does the bucket need special permission do it can accept multipart or resumable upload.

```
from google.cloud import storage

try:
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
    blob = bucket.blob('blob-name')
    blob.upload_from_filename(zip_path, content_type='application/gzip')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error in uploading {zip_path}')
    print(e)
```

We run this inside a Kubernetes pod so the permissions get picked up by storage.Client() call automatically.

We already tried these:

- Can't upload with gsutil because the container is Python 3 and [gsutil does not run in python 3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/29).
- [Tried this example](https://dev.to/sethmichaellarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h):  but runs into the same error:  `('Response headers must contain header', 'location')`
- [There is also this library.](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html#resumable-uploads) But it is basically alpha quality with little activity and no commits for a year.
- Upgraded to google-cloud-storage==1.13.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you upload large files from outside the pod?

Comment: yes. it turns out that credentials picked up automatically from the kubernetes service account was problematic. Will have to look at what that account was and how was it that it was working at some point and then stopped working. creating a new service account and loading the credentials explicitly solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was indeed the credentials. Somehow the error message was very miss-leading. When we loaded the credentials explicitly the problem went away.

```
 # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
 storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my node pools had been spec'd with

```
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
```

and changing it to

```
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
```

fixed the error. As described in [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-resumable-media-python/issues/63) the problem is an uninformative error message.